# how to plot the functions in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to plot a linear function as y=40-0.2x and an hyperbola as y=5/x. How could I make it? I've tried, a code from [this document](http://paws.wcu.edu/tsfoguel/tikzpgfmanual.pdf) in p. 160, but the curve wasn't in the same page with the axes.

**EDIT:** Having used the Tikz method mentionned below, I would like to make a graph for y=5/(x-1)+1.

The result as it is shown in Microsoft Mathematics is:
[image]

However, using LaTeX, I don't have the same result. My code is:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage{ucs} 
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=0.08,yscale=0.09,domain=0.140:60,samples=800]
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (65,0) node[below] {$x$};
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,35) node[left] {$y$};
    \foreach \i in {10,20,...,50} {
        \draw (\i,1) -- (\i,-1) node[below] {$\i$};
    }
    \foreach \i in {5,10,...,30} {
        \draw (1,\i) -- (-1,\i) node[left] {$\i$};
    }
    \draw[green] plot (\x,{5/(\x-1)+1});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Where is my fault?

Comment: You could have a look at `pgfplots`, there are plenty of examples in the manual and here on the site. `pgfplots` is built on TikZ, but is specifically for creating plots if functions or data. Also, note that the manual you link to is for a very old version of `pgf`/TikZ, see [CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) or [texdoc.net](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgf) for a more recent version.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

## Remarks

Keep in mind for both methods, that 5/x has a singularity at 0. At this point the function value will be infinity, which is kind of hard to draw for PGF and will therefore throw an error:

- `` ! Package PGF Math Error: You've asked me to divide `5' by `0', but I cannot divide any number by `0' (in '{5/0}'). ``
- `? Dimensions too large`

## Method 1: Using Ti*k*Z

The advantage of using Ti*k*Z here is, that you can easily place nodes on the plot. The disadvantage is, that you have to scale x and y dimension, because else the drawing will be 220cm wide.

### Implementation

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=0.04,yscale=0.08,domain=0.125:220,samples=400]
    \draw[->] (-10,0) -- (225,0) node[below] {$x$};
    \draw[->] (0,-5) -- (0,45) node[left] {$y$};
    \foreach \i in {50,100,...,200} {
        \draw (\i,1) -- (\i,-1) node[below] {$\i$};
    }
    \foreach \i in {10,20,...,40} {
        \draw (1,\i) -- (-1,\i) node[left] {$\i$};
    }
    \draw[blue] plot (\x,{40-0.2*\x});
    \draw[red] plot (\x,{5/\x});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

> [image: tikz]

## Method 2: Using PGFPlots

This is much more elegant and the code is much shorter.

### Implementation

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[domain=0.125:220,samples=400]
        \addplot+[mark=none] {40-0.2*x};
        \addplot+[mark=none] {5/x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        domain=0.125:220,
        xmin=-10, xmax=220,
        ymin=-5, ymax=45,
        samples=400,
        axis y line=center,
        axis x line=middle,
    ]
        \addplot+[mark=none] {40-0.2*x};
        \addplot+[mark=none] {5/x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

> [image: pgfplots1] [image: pgfplots2]

## Method 3: PSTricks (Just for fun)

Using the package `pst-plot` you get access to advanced plotting features. Also PSTricks is much faster than Ti*k*Z for plotting, because it makes use of the Postscript language.

### Implementation

Compile with `xelatex` or `latex -> dvips -> ps2pdf`.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[xAxisLabel=$x$,yAxisLabel=$y$](-0.5,0)(0.5,6.5)
\begin{psgraph}[arrows=->,Dx=50,Dy=10](0,0)(-10,-5)(220,45){8cm}{6cm}
    \psplot[plotpoints=200,linecolor=blue]{0}{220}{40 0.2 x mul sub}
    \psplot[plotpoints=200,linecolor=red]{0.125}{220}{5 x div}
\end{psgraph}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}[xAxisLabel=$x$,yAxisLabel=$y$,xAxisLabelPos={c,-12},yAxisLabelPos={-35,c}](-1,-1)(0.5,6.5)
\begin{psgraph}[axesstyle=frame,xticksize=-5 45,yticksize=-10 220,Dx=50,Dy=10](0,0)(-10,-5)(220,45){8cm}{6cm}
    \psplot[plotpoints=200,linecolor=blue]{0}{220}{40 0.2 x mul sub}
    \psplot[plotpoints=200,linecolor=red]{0.125}{220}{5 x div}
\end{psgraph}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: ps1] [image: ps2]

Comment: Except for my edit in question, I have just another one: when we use PGFPlots can we have only the x-axis and the y-axis, and NOT a whole box?

Comment: @giannis: I adjusted my answer.

Comment: You could just do `axis lines=center`. (For reference, @giannis, see the manual section **4.8.9 Axis lines**.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. You are right. I adapted this in my follow up answer.

Answer (score 9):

## Answer to the edit

You need to adjust the plot limits by hand. There is no way around that, because no plotting software in the world can know, what limits you want.

### Implementation

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=1.5,yscale=0.04,domain=1.037:4,samples=800]
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (4.5,0) node[below] {$x$};
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,135) node[left] {$y$};
    \foreach \i in {1,2,...,4} {
        \draw (\i,1) -- (\i,-1) node[below] {$\i$};
    }
    \foreach \i in {20,40,...,130} {
        \draw (0.05,\i) -- (-0.05,\i) node[left] {$\i$};
    }

    \draw[green] plot (\x,{5/(\x-1)+1});
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        domain=1.037:4,
        xmin=0, xmax=4.5,
        ymin=0, ymax=135,
        samples=800,
        axis lines=center,
    ]
        \addplot+[mark=none,color=green] {5/(x-1)+1};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

> [image: tikz] [image: pgfplots]

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun with PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12mm,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\psset{plotpoints=200,linewidth=1pt,algebraic,xAxisLabel=$x$,yAxisLabel=$y$}

\def\f{40-0.2*x}
\def\g{5/x}

\begin{document}

\begin{psgraph}[arrows=->,Dx=50,Dy=10](0,0)(-10,-5)(220,45){8cm}{6cm}
    \psplot[linecolor=blue]{0}{220}{\f}
    \psplot[linecolor=red]{0.125}{220}{\g}
\end{psgraph}

\vspace{1cm}
\psset{xAxisLabelPos={c,-12},yAxisLabelPos={-35,c}}
\begin{psgraph}[axesstyle=frame,xticksize=-5 45,yticksize=-10 220,Dx=50,Dy=10](0,0)(-10,-5)(220,45){8cm}{6cm}
    \psplot[linecolor=blue]{0}{220}{\f}
    \psplot[linecolor=red]{0.125}{220}{\g}
\end{psgraph}

\end{document}
```

[image]