# How to plot a function

Tags: graphics, graphs

Hello I am new to this stackexchange, and I have a question in regards to how one plots a function.  I have done research, and I have seen this question:

[The Question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131631/function-graphs)

I have even tried programming it but it does not come up, and the function I would like to graph, and generally learn how to plot any function is the sqrt(9-x)^.5

Here is the bit of code which I have been working on:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subfigure}

\begin{figure}
\centering  
\subfigure
{  
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xmin=-1.5,ymin=-1.5,ymax=1.5]
    \addplot+[domain=0.0001:1.5,unbounded coords=jump,samples=301] {(9-x)^(0.5)};
    \addlegendentry{$f(x)=\sqrt{x}$}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
%
\end{figure}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) It will be beneficial to others if you extend this to a full by minimal document. Then it is easier to for example verify that you have loaded the necessary packages in you preamble for this example to work

Comment: @marmot its the \sqrt{9-x}

Comment: @daleif There are all the packages

Comment: That is not a minimal example, there is no documentclass and no begin/end document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! This is an attempt to summarize some aspects of the comments by @daleif and myself.

1. You got an empty plot because you set `ymax=1.5` but the function assumes larger values in the domain you are plotting it, so you effectively clip the plot away.
2. You are using the `subfigure` package. It is generally recommended to use the `subcaption` package instead.
3. Your code does not quite make an MWE. As pointed out by @daleif, it is lacking a `\documentclass` as well as `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`. And you are loading packages multiple times, and `pgfplots` already loads `tikz`, which loads `graphicx`.

This qualifies as a MWE and takes into account the above points.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{subcaption} 
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering  
  \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xmin=-0.1,xmax=1.6,ymin=1.5,ymax=3.5,
    xlabel={$x$},ylabel={$f(x)$}]
    \addplot+[domain=0.0001:1.5,unbounded coords=jump,samples=301] {(9-x)^(0.5)};
    \addlegendentry{$f(x)=\sqrt{9-x}$}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Caption of a figure.}
    \label{fig:ASubFigure}  
  \end{subfigure}   
\caption{Caption of a figure.}
\label{fig:AFigure}  
\end{figure}

Figure~\ref{fig:ASubFigure} is a subfigure of figure~\ref{fig:AFigure}.
\end{document}
```

[image]