# Plotting a basic function in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

How can I plot a function in latex?for example, if I simply want to draw a decreasing function in first quadrant say f(x) = 1/x and draw dashed line to join (2,0) to (2,1/2) and solid line to join (2,1/2) to (0,1/2).

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/105584/110998 as a starting point. Or https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/121799/110998. Or https://latexdraw.com/plot-a-function-and-data-in-latex/ Just google for `latex plot function`

Comment: Have a look at the [tikz package](https://pgf-tikz.github.io/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf). For example, within a `tikzpicture` environment you can do `\draw (2, 0) -- (2, 0.5);` to draw a line from (2, 0) to (2, 0.5). For more complicated plots there is a plot command, `\draw plot (\x, f(\x));` where `f` is some function that either you define or a built in function. For even more complicated plots have a look at [pgfplots](https://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf).

Comment: Can you please draw above one only, because I'm a beginner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to learn is experimenting, you could try using tikz and pgfplots:

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}
 
\begin{document}
 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin = 0, xmax = 30,
    ymin = 0, ymax = 2.0]
    \draw [dashed] (2, 0) -- (2, 0.5);
    \draw (2, 0.5) -- (0, 0.5);
    \addplot[
        domain = 0:30,
        samples = 100,
        smooth,
        thick,
    ] {1/x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
 
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot of your result to the answer?

Comment: Thank you for answering. Can you please add how to label axes as X and Y and function as f(x) and lines as x=a and y=b on this picture. It will be very helpful.

Comment: Add `xlabel={x-axis label}` and `ylabel={y-axis label}` to the `\begin{axis}` command